# I want to add 'created_by' and 'modified_by' fields to my Django models, How do I do that?

Tags: django

My custom user model in `account.models.py`:

```
class MyRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    location_list=[
        ('abc', 'abc'),
        ('def', 'def'),
        ]
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=location_list, default=None)
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    is_active=models.BooleanField()
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'designation']
    objects=FirstManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

A model in `sample.models.py`:

```
class LockData(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE, default=None)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    lock=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So, along with `created_on` and `modified_on` fields, I also want 'created_by' and 'modified_by' fields. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

We'll start with functional views. Let's assume you have a form that has been submitted to a view to create a new model:

```
def create_lock_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = lock_data_create_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.created_by = request.user
            form.instance.modified_by = request.user
            form.save()
    else:
        form=lock_data_create_form()
     #...render template etc
```

Similarly, in your edit view

```
def edit_lock_data(request, lock_id):
    lock = get_object_or_404(LockData, pk = lock_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = data_lock_edit_form(request.POST, instance=lock)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.modified_by = request.user
            form.save()
    else:
        form=lock_data_edit_form()
    #...render template etc
```

If you are using class based views, you simply need to place the contents of the form.is_valid() conditional in a form_valid() function, while rembering to use self when referring to the request eg,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user #only use for create
    form.instance.modified_by = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```